# How can I use photoshop files as brushes?

Tags: workflow, sculpting, external-applications

I have some `.psd` files and I want to use them as brushes for sculpting, but I can not find an way to import them. I've already tried to add the brushes using append, but don't get how to use them.

**Q:** Is there any way to use brushes from a `.psd` file?

Answer (score 1):

So according to your comment you can import a psd, you can also convert your file to .jpg or .png, then open the <kbd>N</kbd>  panel, create a new texture, and in the *Properties panel > Texture*, load the image. Don't forget to enable *Dyntopo* if you mesh is low-poly. Also, choose the *Mapping* mode you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it's working ! :)

However another question, do you know how I can add this brushes, add them a thumbnails and save it for always in Blender, like if i was using the append function ?

Comment: Oh, and FYI .psd is working :)

Comment: oh ok I didn't know I'm going to edit my answer then

Comment: I know that Blender team is working on an asset management window, for the moment I guess you need to either use an addon, or save a default file with the brushes appended (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend and File > Defaulfs > Save Startup File)? Maybe try that?

Comment: Well, i've just saved the project and brushes also saved :)